# Video object detection in Unity3d

Tags: c#, python, opencv, unity-game-engine, emgucv

*I have a **video** which is capture from a moving car and video showing plenty of details like pools, human, cars/buses, roads, etc, etc.*

The video I am playing in unity3d and camera Showing that video and user is allow to click on video. I want to get different information from the videos like if someone clicked on video (like clicked on a bus object), then, unity UI should show that it is a bus object. **It something like object detection in video within unity environment**.

From last couple of days I searched and found different things like :

1. [**OpenCV for Unity3d**](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/21088) an asset on asset store but cost is the problem.
   So is there any tut or custom way available that i should write it
   myself?
2. [**Yolo**](https://github.com/llSourcell/YOLO_Object_Detection) but its in python and i found no integration guide that I
   follow and integrate it in unity.
3. as comment suggested [**EmguCV Unity**](https://github.com/neutmute/emgucv/tree/master/Emgu.CV.Unity) is also an option but its github don't conver any guide, i downloaded its
   project there is not sample or docs. And [its paid version](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/24681) cost is about 400$.

Is there any third thing compatible with unity3d? or do i can use/integrate above given projects in unity?

Comment: IMHO stick with the python. It's easy to integrate IronPython with your Unity project and since Yolo is free .. you do not have to throw any money. Take a look at [this tutorial](http://techartsurvival.blogspot.bg/2013/12/embedding-ironpython-in-unity-tech-art.html) It would be even better to use OpenCV and use Mixed Assemblies.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://github.com/neutmute/emgucv/tree/master/Emgu.CV.Unity

Comment: You can run in Unity, and send the click coordinates to a rest-api with python to return you what it is.

Comment: @UmairM thanks umair but there is no comprehesive docs about emug unity. i have downloaded the project but there is no demo scene and no documentation.

Comment: @user1767754 Thanks for clue but it seems less easy. Any tut link will highly be appreciated. anyway thanks

Comment: @m.rogalski irfonpython will run on editor? how can it help with yolo?

Comment: If you configure different behavior for editor then yes, it is possible to run IronPython inside the editor.

Comment: There is demo folder inside the project. I am sure you can get the idea. Sometimes you have to learn without tutorials :)

Comment: @UmairM there is no  demo scene in the unity emgu project.

Comment: I would [disagree](https://github.com/neutmute/emgucv/tree/master/Emgu.CV.Unity/demo)